# Как использовать корутины для измения значений полей xml?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx-coroutines

Смысл программы  - Есть 2 кнопки: action и exit. При нажатии на action - текст в отдельном поле должен начать изменяться в бесконечном цикле. Exit - выход из программы (ее корректное закрытие). Основной Activity у меня выглядит так:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var btn_action: Button
    private lateinit var btn_exit: Button
    private lateinit var txt: TextView


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        btn_action = findViewById(R.id.btn_action)
        btn_action = findViewById(R.id.btn_exit)
        txt = findViewById(R.id.Text_data)
        txt.text = "Hola"


        btn_action.setOnClickListener {
            lifecycleScope.launch{
                hola()
            }
        }

       btn_exit.setOnClickListener(
           exitProcess(0)
      )

    }
fun hola() {
        var count = 0
        while (true) {
            count++
            txt.text = "${count}"
            delay(500)
        }

    }
```

При запуске программа либо вылетает, либо не выполняет функцию hola. Как можно исправить этот код чтобы программа заработала?

Comment: понятие `вылетает` довольно растяжимое, уточните пожалуйста ошибку

Comment: В случае вылета - все, что написано выглядит так: 
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:34907', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:34907', transport: 'socket'

Comment: Если удаляю  btn_exit.setOnClickListener( - вылеты прекращаются, но кнопка action не срабатывает

Comment: Проверьте в каком потоке вы цикл запускаете (Выведите в логи что-то типа `Thread.currentThread().name`) - если из главного (`main`) то замените поток примерно так: `withContext(Dispathers.io()) { /*тут код цикла*/ }`. При этом надо вьюхи менять из главного, т.е. `txt.text = "${count}"` надо завернуть в `withContext(Dispathers.main()) { /*тут код назначения текста в TextView*/ }`

Comment: Ну и странно завершать программу закрытием процесса. Лучше вместо `while(true)` какой-то флаг использовать, который будет меняться и тем самым завешать цикл

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ошибку. Проблема оказалась очень простой - два раза задал btn_action с переприсвоением. Следующий код - заработал.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var btn_action: Button
    private lateinit var btn_exit: Button
    private lateinit var txt: TextView


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        btn_action = findViewById(R.id.btn_action)
        btn_exit = findViewById(R.id.btn_exit)
        txt = findViewById(R.id.Text_data)
        txt.text = "Hola"


        btn_action.setOnClickListener {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                hola()
            }
            txt.text = "222222222"
        }

        btn_exit.setOnClickListener {
            exitProcess(0)
        }

    }

    suspend fun hola() {
        var count = 0
        while (true) {
            count++
            txt.text = "${count}"
            delay(500)
        }
    }


}
```

ЮрийСПБ, cпасибо за за комментарии, они очень помогли. Попробую доделать полностью в соотвествии с ними